# If column X contains String then find position of substring in column Y - PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the starting position of a string in an URL contained in column['url'] if column ['Existe'] contains "F" or "D". I'm new to Python and I'm trying to replicate a workflow from Excel in Python and after an hour of trying methods with lambda, numpy.where or numpy.select, and searching the web, I had to ask for help.

I've tried applying the following code, but this only returns that the value exists, but doesn't actually gives me the position in the string. What I currently have is:

```
df['Start']= ["/t/" in x[0] and "F" in x[1] for x in zip(df['url'],df['Existe'])]
```

Basically, the results it gives me is the following:

```
       order     id       date      time  URL                    typedCount transition  Existe  Start
0          0  14438   1/3/2021  14:49:37  messenger.com/t/xxxxx          0       link       F   True
1          1  14437   1/3/2021  14:49:18  messenger.com/t/xxxxx          0       link       F   True
```

What I'm trying to do is to find the starting position of "/t/" in df['url'] if "F" exists in df['Existe'] and placing the result in a new column, df['Start']. I have to use this conditional because df['Existe'] contains both "F" and "D", and it has to look for "/t/" if it's "F", and "/@me/" if it's "D".

The result I'm looking for is:

```
       order     id       date      time  URL                    typedCount transition  Existe  Start
0          0  14438   1/3/2021  14:49:37  messenger.com/t/xxxxx          0       link       F   14
1          1  14437   1/3/2021  14:49:18  messenger.com/t/xxxxx          0       link       F   14
```

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Avoid Looping Over Rows

When manipulating data with pandas, [it is typically best to avoid looping over rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/5075720). Working with logic that only operates on certain rows, it is better to begin by explicitly identifying those rows. The subset of rows where the value of column `Existe` is equal to `"F"` is:

```
has_f = df["Existe"] == "F"
```

Now you can use `has_f` to select only the rows you care about in `df`.

When working in pandas, try to use built-in pandas (or numpy) functions as much as possible. While you might not notice the difference when working with small DataFrames, any raw Python code you write and apply with `df.apply()` will perform poorly compared to the optimized code included in the pandas and numpy packages. Fortunately, pandas has [vectorized string functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-string-methods) that can help you here. To find the location of a substring in each row of a column of strings, try the following:

```
t_locations = df["URL"].str.find("/t/")
```

This produces a `Series` of integer locations of the first occurrence of the substring `"/t/"` in the column `URL`. You can do the same for `"/@me/"`.

Combining these two features of pandas requires using the [`df.loc` indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) to select the rows and columns you care about and only applying the `str.find()` function to those values:

```
df["Start"] = -1  # some default value
has_f = df["Existe"] == "F"

df.loc[has_f, "Start"] = df.loc[has_f, "URL"].str.find("/t/")
# The "~" here returns the inverse of the Boolean Series
df.loc[~has_f, "Start"] = df.loc[~has_f, "URL"].str.find("/@me/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using the apply() routine of DataFrame:

```
def process_row(row):
    if row['Existe']=='F':
        row['Start']=row['URL'].find('/t/') + 1
    elif row['Existe']=='D':
        row['Start']=row['URL'].find('/@me/') + 1
    return row
df.apply(process_row,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you Fwnr. This, unfortunately, didn't work, and I believe it could be since I didn't provide my code. Anyway, I appreciate your time and work!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you tried to explain with `'F'` and `'D'` so I assumed this example and the output that'll go with it will be below

```
order   id  date    time    URL typedCount  transition  Existe
0   14438   1/3/2021    14:49:37    messenger.com/t/xxxxx   0   link    F
1   14437   1/3/2021    14:49:18    messenger.com/t/xxxxx   0   link    F
2   14437   1/3/2021    14:49:18    messenger.com/t/@me/xxxx    0   link    D
3   14437   1/3/2021    14:49:18    messenger.com/t/@me/xxxx    0   link    FD
4   14437   1/3/2021    14:49:18    messenger.com/nothing/xxxx  0   link    FD
```

Basically you can use `df.apply` to execute a function on your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

def myfunc(row):                                          
     f_pos = -1   
     d_pos = -1   
     if 'F' in row['Existe']:
         f_pos = row['URL'].find('/t')
     if 'D' in row['Existe']:
         d_pos = row['URL'].find('/@me/')
     return f_pos, d_pos
 

df = pd.read_csv("yourfile", sep=",") # change the field separator
df['Start'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

And the output is:

```
    order     id      date      time                         URL  typedCount transition Existe     Start
0      0  14438  1/3/2021  14:49:37       messenger.com/t/xxxxx           0       link      F  (13, -1)
1      1  14437  1/3/2021  14:49:18       messenger.com/t/xxxxx           0       link      F  (13, -1)
2      2  14437  1/3/2021  14:49:18    messenger.com/t/@me/xxxx           0       link      D  (-1, 15)
3      3  14437  1/3/2021  14:49:18    messenger.com/t/@me/xxxx           0       link     FD  (13, 15)
4      4  14437  1/3/2021  14:49:18  messenger.com/nothing/xxxx           0       link     FD  (-1, -1)
```

As you can see you can edit the `myfunc` to fit your needs better as I'm not sure what you meant by both having the `F` and `D`.

It is worth to note that the `str.find()` method will return `-1` if the string can't be found.

I've also set the `myfunc` to return this same `-1` in case no `F` or `D` are found but you can set anything else. For instance if you set it to `-2` or `False` you can quickly know if it didn't find anything because it wasn't in the URL or because no `F` or `D` where in the `Existe` column.

EDIT: In python the indexes starts at 0, meaning the 14th character is at index 13

Comment: Thank you for your answer Plopp. This, unfortunately, didn't work, and I believe it could be since I didn't provide my code. Anyway, I appreciate your time and work!